# Howto easily monitor usage of Eden and Survivor Spaces

Tags: java, garbage-collection

What is the best way howto monitor usage of **Eden** and **Survivor** heap spaces?

I have all the **GC logging options** on but I can see only YoungGen occupation:

> -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log -server  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC  -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -showversion -XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15

I would use [VisualGC](https://blogs.oracle.com/klc/entry/visualgc_plugin_for_visualvm) but cannot find its distribution anywhere. The default distribution of VisualVM that comes with JDK does not come with VisualGC. The [VisualGC plugin links](http://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html) to the VisualGC site are broken.

**UPDATE:** `jstat` is what I was looking for, specifically :

```
    jstat -gcutil -t <pid> <interval> <number_of_samples>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "monitor", you might just need [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html). Check out the -gc* options.

Comment: Yes, this is even better than what I was hoping with the VisualGC plugin.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can use [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) to monitor your Java applications.

Comment: Yes, but it does not come with the VisualGC plugin. The JVisualVM does not show Survivor/Eden space usage by default. Do you know where I can get VisualGC?

Comment: I believe you can install it as a plugin.

Comment: Yes, but as I say in the question, the links to the VisualGC plugin are broken.

Comment: Which link are you talking about? VisualGC plugin can be installed from VisualVM. Go to Tools->Plugins

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html), you can download the relevant plugin center "updates.xml" file, an install it per the instructions.  Then you can install the VisualGC plugin.

But the page also says that you should simply be able to install plugins using "Tools | Plugins | Available Plugins".

The links to projects on `java.net` are often broken in my experience.  You typically have to look harder to find stuff that is hosted there.

Comment: There is no need to download plugins manually. The above page is for the special cases. The second paragraph on the page describes it. `Note that downloading plugins from this page and installing them manually should be used only when experiencing problems with installation using the built-in Plugin Center, for example due to networking problems (no internet access, proxy restrictions etc.). If you don't have networking problems, use Tools | Plugins | Available Plugins to install the plugins directly from the tool.
`. Normally plugins are installed from VisualVM. Go to Tools->Plugins.