# Java Garbage Collection Monitoring

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a project in Netbeans that I am profiling (using Java 7). What I am looking for is, upon a garbage collection, how much memory from the Eden space is going into the Survivor spaces, and if there is any memory overflowing into the Tenured space. On top of that, I am looking for how the Tenured space is growing in size over time.

I print GC stats but I only get info like this:

```
2339.967: [GC 2339.967: [ParNew: 66213K->4522K(69376K), 0.0161101 secs] 284589K->223320K(369484K), 0.0161685 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2344.543: [GC 2344.543: [ParNew: 66218K->4520K(69376K), 0.0161084 secs] 285016K->223739K(369484K), 0.0161647 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2349.118: [GC 2349.118: [ParNew: 66216K->4519K(69376K), 0.0159046 secs] 285435K->224159K(369484K), 0.0159587 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

Anyone know of a way to figure out the information I am looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Use VisualVM which has a GC monitoring plugin.

Comment: See also Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13924565/772000

Comment: JVisualVM is the way to go unless you want to shell out for an expensive profiler like JProfiler (they have freebie open source licenses if you fit that category). JVisualVM is free (as in beer) always.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Excellent suggestion. This program looks promising! Thank you!

Comment: @SnakeDoc Also great information. Thanks!

Comment: `visualgc` beats `visualvm` in richness of information. It visualizes each generation separately on a dashboard. It also shows total GC time and compilation time spent. It is as free as `visualvm`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes but jVisualVM comes pre-installed/included with any Oracle JDK 7 install/download. So nothing more to do, you already have it. Why not use it?

Comment: @SnakeDoc Because you want more details? Because `visuagc` is a *better* tool to monitor the heap? Because it is free, and just one download away?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was going for the "ease of use" angle. It's already there, and visualgc can't show any additional info since it's reading from the same debugger jvisualvm does. Also jvisualvm is official oracle supported, meaning it may have some "tricks" others don't and/or get more supported/updated.

Comment: @SnakeDoc `visualgc` is Oracle's product. It is as supported as `visualvm`. But the point is that `visualvm` has a VisualGC plugin, which is pretty much the same as the standalone version. The difference between these two choices is mostly about startup time and command-line convenience.

Answer (score 14):

Here are some useful GC flags:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintClassHistogram
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
```

-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Upvoting. This *is* a useful answer. To whoever downvoted this answer: downvoting an answer without giving a reason in the comment is not being polite.

Answer (score 6):

A **simple solution** is to use `jstat`, this shows the occuptation of all different memory regions (Eden, Survivor spaces) across all generations.

Use e.g. 
    `jstat -gcutil -t <pid> <interval> <number_of_samples>`

Example output:

```
jstat -gcutil 21891 250 7
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC    YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 12.44   0.00  27.20   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
 12.44   0.00  62.16   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
 12.44   0.00  83.97   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
  0.00   7.74   0.00   9.51  96.70    79    0.177     5    0.495    0.673
  0.00   7.74  23.37   9.51  96.70    79    0.177     5    0.495    0.673
  0.00   7.74  43.82   9.51  96.70    79    0.177     5    0.495    0.673
  0.00   7.74  58.11   9.51  96.71    79    0.177     5    0.495    0.673
```

Explanation:

> The output of this example shows that a young generation collection occurred between the 3rd and 4th sample. The collection took 0.001 seconds and promoted objects from the eden space (E) to the old space (O), resulting in an increase of old space utilization from 9.49% to 9.51%. Before the collection, the survivor space was 12.44% utilized, but after this collection it is only 7.74% utilized.

More heavyweight options are profilers, e.g. JVisualVM with GC monitoring, or the new Java Mission Control with Java 7u40.

Also, consider the following GC options: `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution`, `-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold`.

Comment: Because you are using the default gravitar ;-P

Answer (score 6):

Oracle's JDK comes standard now with `jvisualvm` which is a free profiler. It will show you what's eating up memory, cpu, threads, network time, db access, etc. Yes, it even shows GC time and a bunch of other goodies about GC in general.

Best part, it's free! (and it may already be installed on your system if you have Oracle JDK)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUQqmnmCBbg

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` flag to enable printing more details.

Comment: Why downvote? You didn't mention using this flag anywhere in your question. The output suggested you're using only `-verbose:gc` flag.